# How to filter by multiple criteria?

Tags: emeditor

How to filter by multiple criteria? For example, I want to select columns A = USA & columns B = 20210325，I hope the answer is accompanied by a functional icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Advanced Filter to do this. [image: Toolbar]

Add two conditions for the two columns in Advanced Filter and click Filter.

[image: Advanced Filter]

Comment: Thanks! I learned to use it, It should be noted that after clicking the "Add" function, enter the conditions, and then select the column